# Is it a good idea to use safemysql class to prevent SQL injections?

Tags: php, class, sql-injection

I wanted to know if anyone has expierience with this script/class [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql)? (except the developer of this script)

It is announced to be the safest way for mysql-queries and to prevent sites from sql-injections .. and I do really like the way you can work with it.

But is it really "safe"? Is it good code? … and what about closing the mysql connection which does not happen in this script .. isn't it necessary?

would love to discuss this with you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely the idea is great.
As a matter of fact, this class is safer than other widely advertized solutions like raw PDO, providing *placeholders* not only for the extremely limited set of literals, but for the **everything** that can be put into query.

Having that, it makes the application code dramatically shorter, relieving a developer from manual data formatting.

The only possible drawbacks are

- the ?p placeholder that have to be used with caution.
- the ?a placeholder with empty array put into `NOT IN(?a)` statement
- one have to always keep in mind whitelisting features when dealing with ?u and ?n placeholders. Everything is covered in examples though.

Of course you can easily extend it, adding features you need personally, like closing connections and stuff. That is what OOP exactly for.

Comment: Do you know of any significant 3rd party adoption yet? Sorry, I'm currently working on Postgres, so can't give it a whirl myself. :-3

Comment: ya. but i don't have the feeling that many people use it!? And YOU are the developer of this code. and as i said I really like it – and the fact that it's OOP. But before I am going to integrate it into my system I wanted to know from OTHER people what the think about it. There was 1 post who said that it isn't compatible with >= 5.5 php versions. so what about that. and why has this post disappeared?

Comment: it disappeared because it was out of wrong assumption that class is based on a soon-to-be-deprecated mysql ext, while it is not

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith - If you're talking about NullPointer's answer on this question, he claimed the class uses the deprecated mysql_*() functions but it's obvious it uses mysqli.

Comment: @deceze I have some feedback from people who apparently use it for their projects but I don't know the project names. That's good idea - I'd ask people to share their success(or not) stories. At the moment we are adding named placeholders support into Yii fork, but it is not out yet.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Can you tell me how many people are using it? be honest. I really want to know. On the internet i find nothing about your class except on your git-site and here at stack overflow.

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith sorry that class used mysql_* when i saw last time .. but now it usages mysqli ...i apologize for my mistake .. this class is perfectly fine ...

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith oh, I think you can be sure of 3 people if the number is so important to you. You can also try some ORM (like Doctrine for example) instead of creating plain queries. It has apparently more users.

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith by the way if you choose to use this class, you can count on all the support from me. You can write me to e-mail from the profile

Comment: @YourCommonSense oh wow. that sounds nice. i think i'll give it a try ;)

Comment: other question: does it work with magic_quotes_gpc? or better to turn this off?

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith strictly speaking, magic_quotes_gpc has nothing to do with data security (that's why this feature already **removed completely** from the recent PHP version) but just spoils your data. So, it have to be always turned off.

Comment: Erm, I feel that this answer *really* ought to very clearly mention that you're the library's author. Don't get me wrong - I'm pretty much a fan both of safemysql and of you - but posting what amounts to a positive review of your own library without mentioning that you're the author is kind of dodgy.

Answer (score 6):

Despite the name, I don't think that security is the key point of the class. Don't misunderstand me, I'm not claiming it isn't secure. It actually has security features other libraries don't normally have, such as place-holders for identifiers.

What I mean is that builtin extensions are safe enough if used properly and the typical creative user can skip placeholders as easily as with any other library:

```
$foo = $db->getAll("select * from foo where foo_id={$_POST[foo_id]}");
```

What makes this class different to other alternatives is that:

1. It provides a handy syntax to compose SQL queries from non-scalar data types, e.g. arrays.
2. It provides a built-in feature to compose INSERT queries.
3. It provides a built-in value filter ("whitelist").

... and it doesn't force you to use a poor clone of the SQL language like most fraweworks do (after all it's a helper, not a framework, and proud of it).

The data type place-holders are weird (why do I need to set `?i`/`?s` for single values but not for arrays?) and the author is known for his hate on named parameters (so you won't find them here). But the project doesn't claim to be finished.

To sum up: use it if you like the syntax sugar, not just for security. If something's broken, it's a single 637-line file—you can probably fix it yourself :)

Comment: so you don't think, that it's secure enough? it doesn't prevent from sql injections at all? or how can I interpret this?

Comment: Thank you for taking time to review - it is extremely rare kind of favor one can expect on Stackoverflow. Lack for integer arrays has a very simple explanation: it is just not required, as strings can serve all right. It's just like PDO's `execute()`. The reason for my hate of named placeholders is simple too - you need them mainly to create a long-winded insert queries - a case already covered. For the other cases most of time they makes code unnecessarily bloated, adding no readability. Nevertheless I am thinking of implementing them as a part of Yii fork query builder anyway.

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith the meaning is: it isn't "fool-proof". It can't *prevent* you from writing unsafe queries. But as long as you are using placeholders instead of injecting variables into query - it is safe. No other solution offers it too, save for some very limited ORMs, probably.